# About Net work . My url is not working in my net work, but it came in another net connection

Tags: networking

My URL is not working in my network connection, but it came in another net connection. how to fix this.

When I type the URL in the browser it shows

> "This webpage is not available"
>
> ```
> "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"
> ```

But the same URL coming in another system which is connected in another network connection.

Give me some directions to solve this problems.

Comment: This is an impossibly vague question. You've given us no clues even to what programming language you're working with, and you're showing us no code. I've no idea what "the same url Comming in another system which is connected in anothere net work connection" is meant to mean.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons -

1. You are not connected to network(your internet is not working).
2. You typed incorrect URL.
3. URL is blocked by ISP.